How to upload your fine-tuned model on HuggingFace and use it as an API? Or Should i use GCP?
Goal: I am trying to upload my finetuned model on huggingface, and then I want to use it as an API for my Android and IOS application, but I am not sure about the process. I also have tried to look around on GCP, it seems they have models like Llama 2 etc but i have not seen any option to upload my model and use it as an API.

The basic process to using your custom model in HuggingFace:

Fine-tune the model with HuggingFace transformer [1].

Upload to HuggingFace Model Hub

Use the Interface API with your application.


You may view the docs for more information - Overview.
Regarding GCP, you can use Vertex AI as an alternative:

Get predictions from custom trained models

Get online predictions from a custom trained model


[1]. https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/get-online-predictions
